# Epplus Csharp | How to manipulate already opened(in use) Excel File

Tags: epplus

Epplus Csharp | How to manipulate already opened(in use) Excel File. it works only when Excel file is closed. I can do like closing before code execution and reopen again, but do not think it's a way to go as my file contains more than 50000 rows (file size is big). Please advise, how to figure it out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

**It is only possible, if the file is opened for reading by a third-party**, but not for writing.

If the third-party opened the file for writing, your attempt to open the same file even just for reading will result in `System.IO.IOException`. In fact, it's all about `FileStream` and not specific to EpPlus and ExcelPackage. Example in terms of .NET:

```
var fileStream1 = new FileStream(@"File.ext", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var fileStream2 = new FileStream(@"File.ext", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

will work just fine. But the second line of the following fragment:

```
var fileStream1 = new FileStream(@"File.ext", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
var fileStream2 = new FileStream(@"File.ext", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

will result in a `System.IO.IOException`.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than using a FileInfo to open the ExcelPackage workbook, use a stream:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
ExcelPackage pkg = new ExcelPackage(fs);
```

- path is the path to the file that you would otherwise use for FileInfo
- FileMode says you want to open it
- FileAccess says you want to read it
- FileShare says that other programs can read/write.

With the workbook specified by path open in excel, you will be able to read lines from the file, but will get an exception if you try to call `ExcelPackage.Save()`.