# Extracting Data from Excel Sheet returns Empty When File is kept Open in Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

I'm using the following code to extract data from sheets within a workbook using EPPlus. The code works fine, except when the workbook is open in Excel. The code returns no data when the Excel file is kept open by the user. How can I get over this issue?

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@file);

using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
                {
                    label_snum.Text = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Count.ToString();
                    // Itterate through workbook sheets
                    foreach (var sheet in package.Workbook.Worksheets)
                    {
                        label_csheet.Text = sheet.Name;
                        // Itterate through each column until final column
                        for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.Dimension.End.Column; i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 1; j <= sheet.Dimension.End.Row; j++)
                            {
                                if (sheet.Cells[j, i].Text.Length != 0)
                                {

                                }
                             }    
                    }  
                }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19970755/3286163

Comment: @singularhum Thanks... will take a look at it.

Comment: @singularhum works perfect. Thanks :).why dont you add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about trying to connect to Excel file using a connection string instead of trying to access the opened file?

```
ConnectionString: Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\PathtoYourExcelFile.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
```

Then you can use Linq/SQL queries to pull in the data.

```
"SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]"
```

Comment: Thanks,but i dont want to redo the same stuff already done in EPPlus.

Comment: No problem. I haven't looked into it but have you marked the XLSX file for collaboration?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49620338/3286163) that I originally linked as a comment.

```
new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
```

To further explain, a file cannot be read when passing a `FileInfo` to `ExcelPackage` if it is being used by another process.

[Prior to v4.5.1 of EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/commit/2960542bf87e5458c3aa3fe092d2449dbaae7bb4#diff-b2a93c2350b6beccf246b719e4a39500), `ExcelPackage` uses `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes` to load a file. [`ReadAllBytes`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,920) uses the `FileShare.Read` setting which is incorrect because Excel opens files using the `FileShare.ReadWrite` setting.

When you open an already opened file, you also need to use the [same `FileShare` setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/898017/3286163). So by using a `FileStream`, you can supply the correct `FileShare`.

[From v4.5.1](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/v4.5.1/EPPlus/ExcelPackage.cs#L645), `ExcelPackage` now does this for you now when passing a `FileInfo`.